# How can I add a link to my Xamarin.Forms application so it opens a web page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I know how to code the buttons, how to use Command but what I would like some advice on is if there's a way to open a web page from the C# code in my application?  Is this something I need to do async and is there some function I can call that will do this that works in forms back-end code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is would open a web page in your default browser

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://something.com"))
```

I don't think it should be `async` function in any way

If you want to write in as `async` download **`Xamarin.Essentials`** plugin and write it as

```
public async Task<bool> OpenBrowser(Uri uri)
 {
        return await Browser.OpenAsync(uri, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
 }
```

This method returns after the browser was launched and not necessarily closed by the user. The `bool` result indicates whether the launching was successful or not.

Read on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?tabs=android) for more information.